# How to add more than one custom metadata as filter on the post list page?

Tags: filters, post-meta

To add a filter based on metadata to a post we use the following format:

```
$wp_query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'meta_key_name';
$wp_query->query_vars['meta_value'] = meta_value;
```

How can I add more than one metadata field?

Answer (score 0):

Those are the old style meta query arguments. You should use `meta_query` instead, which will allow querying on multiple meta keys with conditions and nesting. See the [Custom Field Parameters section in `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) for examples.